# cortar string de nucleotideos de DNA

Tags: python, string

Alguem poderia me ajudar nessa questao:

Tenho uma sequencia de nucleotídeos *(letras: `A`,`T`,`C`,`G`)*, preciso retirar parte dessa sequencia e deixar somente nove nucleotídeos começando por `ATG` e terminando por `TAA`... exemplo

```
AATG ATGCGTTAA AGTCAT
```

Preciso somente da sequencia do meio...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Poderá fazer:

```py
todosOsNucleotideos = "AATG ATGCGTTAA AGTCAT"
apenasATGCGTTAA = todosOsNucleotideos[5:14]
```

Comment: estou no Python, desculpa nao ter citado antes!!Pode me ajuda tbm?

Comment: Ajustei a resposta, depois adiciona esta informação na sua pergunta.

Comment: nao deu certo ainda !!

Comment: Ops, my bad, acertei.

Answer (score 0):

Solução é iterar sobre cada nucleotídeo da sequência de DNA, pegar o nucleotídeo + os dois seguintes e checar se essa tríade é "ATG". Caso positivo, repetimos o meso processo até encontrarmos o TAA:

```
dna = "AATGATGCGTTAAAGTCAT"
result = ""
for index in range(len(dna)):
    start = dna[index:index+3]
    if start == 'ATG':
        sliced_dna = dna[index:]
        for subindex in range(len(sliced_dna)):
            end = sliced_dna[subindex:subindex+3]
            if end == 'TAA':
                result = sliced_dna[:subindex+3]
print(result)  # ATGCGTTAA
```

Note que a operação para encontrar o início e o fim da sequência é basicamente a mesma - poderíamos simplificar este código definindo funções ao invés de for loops dentro de for loops, mas o funcionamento é o mesmo.

Da forma como escrevi, o programa procura pela última sequência "TAA", se quiser parar na primeira será necessário usar `break` para acabar com os loops precocemente.

Comment: muito obrigada!! Deu certo e eu entendi!!